# Converting from google translate widget to cloud api using javascript and ajax

Tags: ajax, google-translate

We develop and maintain a large number websites which have used the 'old' translate widget for quite some time. Recently, we've undertaken an effort to make all these sites ADA compliant.  As it turns out, the widget's implementation is NOT ADA compliant and, it's being deprecated anyway, so our strategy is to move forward and implement the Cloud Translation API.

Many of the site pages are quite large and contain a lot of markup within the body.  The body of most site's home pages is in the vicinity of 20KB. Other site pages are probably somewhat smaller. So, rather than doing a POST to an endpoint on the server which would, in turn, post to the api and then have to return the content to the browser, we believe the correct approach is to access the api directly from the browser and clearly, if we were to post the html content of the body, the api should return the body with the markup intact with the translated text.

The only example we've been able to find shows code with a non-ajax $.get(...) translating a short text string. We're wondering if there might be other examples out there which more closely address what we're trying to accomplish.

One other side note: removing the markup from one of these 20KB bodies results in a reduction in size to a bit over 5KB, so potentially doing this could result in a significant cost savings for our clients. If we were to do this by creating an array of strings to translate as part of the post, is it possible to instruct the api to do a batch translate, which would allow us to replace the original strings with the translated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only available batch requests for translations would be this [1]. This requires the use of cloud storage, where the files should be and where the translated files go. As per your explanation, I am unsure if this could be of use for you.

I have found this post [2] which has a workaround that may be of use for you if it is possible for you to concatenate what needs to be translated. Basically, the workaround would be creating a string which is a concatenation of the strings that need to be translated and split it once it is translated based on a delimiter value.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/batch-translation

[2] [Bulk translation of a big set of records via google translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189037/bulk-translation-of-a-big-set-of-records-via-google-translate)